# Command Line Windows 7 Issue

Tags: windows-7, path, cmd, dos

I have this strange issue with command line in a windows 7 machine.
The PATH variable is correctly set but I can only execute programs by its full file name.
For example if I type 'where' it says command not found, but 'where.exe' works properly.

Somebody knows how to solve this issue, as I suspect it is the reason of another problem I have. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. We are not general tech support.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Anyways the answer was useful. Does this belongs to server fault?

Comment: no, not really serverfault either. this isn't a server issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `PATHEXT` variable to include `exe`.

This environment variable determines which extensions are "optional"; it's what allows you to leave out the `.exe`.

On my system, it's

```
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```